# Timeline change css on enter view port

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timeline.js

Am trying to change the background color of the timeline on scroll like on [this site](https://somaliastabilityke-public.sharepoint.com/apply).My replication of the sample is [development site](http://ssf.masterpiecefusion.com/apply/). Take a look at the [codepen](http://codepen.io/GotaloveCode/pen/dMRNjq) I tried using. The closest I have come to replicating it is with the code below which makes the change in color on each timeline circle flicker on/off on scroll.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
function onScroll() {
  $('.cd-timeline-block').each( function() {
    if( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.05 && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('cd-inactive') ) {
      $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').removeClass('cd-inactive').addClass('cd-active');
      $(this).find('.cd-date').addClass('cd-ssf-color');
    } else {
      $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').addClass('cd-inactive').removeClass('cd-active');
      $(this).find('.cd-date').removeClass('cd-ssf-color');
    }
  });
};

$(window).scroll(onScroll);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modification to the above code.

CodePen link: 
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzqWVm

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $timeline_block = $('.cd-timeline-block');
  var firstelm = $timeline_block.first();

    //on scolling, show/animate timeline blocks when enter the viewport
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      var _win = $(window), iselm = null;
      $timeline_block.each(function(index) {
        var _this = $(this);
        if (((_this.offset().top - _win.height())) <= (_win.scrollTop())) {
          iselm = _this;
        }

      });
      if (_win.scrollTop() < $(firstelm).offset().top) {
        iselm = $(firstelm);
      }

      if (iselm) {
        $('.cd-active').removeClass('cd-active').addClass('cd-inactive');
          iselm.find('.cd-timeline-img').removeClass('cd-inactive').addClass('cd-active');

        if ((iselm.offset().top - _win.height()) > (_win.scrollTop() * 0.75)) {
          $('.cd-date').removeClass('cd-ssf-color');
        }
        iselm.find('.cd-date').addClass('cd-ssf-color');
      }
    });
  });
```

Continuing each loop on scroll might not work properly.

Comment: Please include the relevant code *in the answer itself* and don't highlight random text as "code" to avoid the block that StackOverflow has to force you to do so

Comment: Also, "Stage 2" is never highlighted in your example

Comment: Thanks @ZachSaucier I am little bit confused while formating comments. I didn't highlight things in text. But while submitting comments those colors got applied. I try my best before submit comments. :)

Comment: @santy I don't get it.It works fine on the codepen but on the live site it highlights only 1st and last.Am upvoting this answer coz it works on codepen but am still stumped.

Comment: @santy it works fine scratch that.Must have made an error on local copy.Thanks.Marking this as correct!